# Wrong Result in the CTE Hierarchical Tree

Tags: sql-server, tree, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I've this Tree

- Country

  - Region

    - City

      - Association

        - Center

          - School

            - Class

[image]

i have this Query here

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
  SELECT T1.ID, UserId,  NULL AS PARENT_ID, T1.GroupID, G.EntityLevelID
  FROM UserJobs T1
  INNER JOIN [GROUP] G ON T1.GROUPID = G.ID
  inner join EntityLevel el on G.EntityLevelID = el.Id 
  WHERE T1.UserID = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT T2.ID, T2.UserId,  EL.ParentID, T2.GroupID, G.EntityLevelID
  FROM UserJobs T2
  INNER JOIN [GROUP] G ON T2.GROUPID = G.ID
  inner join EntityLevel el on G.EntityLevelID = el.Id
  INNER JOIN MyCTE itms ON EL.ParentID >= itms.ID
)

SELECT B.*,  C.*, A.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM  MyCTE) A
INNER JOIN [USER] B ON A.UserID = B.ID
INNER JOIN [Group] C ON A.GroupID = C.ID
order by a.GroupID ;
```

if i run this query for userID = 1

it will gives me correct Data (it will bring all the users that are under UserA = UserID = 1)

```
1   UserA   1   Country Manager 1   1   1   NULL    1   1
2   UserB   2   Region Manager  2   2   2   1   2   2
8   UserH   2   Region Manager  2   8   8   1   2   2
3   UserC   3   City Manager    3   3   3   2   3   3
9   UserI   3   City Manager    3   9   9   2   3   3
4   UserD   4   Association Manager 4   4   4   3   4   4
10  UserJ   4   Association Manager 4   10  10  3   4   4
5   UserE   5   Center Manager  5   5   5   4   5   5
6   UserF   6   School Manager  6   6   6   5   6   6
7   UserG   7   Teacher 7   7   7   6   7   7
```

this is actually what i looking for, but the problem comes when i need to get the user under `UserI` ID equal `9`

The Result is :

```
9   UserI   3   City Manager    3   9   9   NULL    3   3
```

and that's wrong because `UserI` has one user Under him which is `UserJ`

so, the result must looks like

```
    9   UserI   3   City Manager    3   9   9   NULL    3   3
   10   UserJ   4   Association Manager 4   10  10  NULL    4   4
```

same error Occurs in **UserID = 3** which gives me a `UserJ` which is out of tree

---

Script And Data is Here :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Assocation](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CityID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Assocation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Center]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 8:33:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Center](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AssociationID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Center] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[City]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 8:33:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RegionID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_City] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Class]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 8:33:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Class](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SchoolID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Class] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Country]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 8:33:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Country] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EntityLevel]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 8:33:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntityLevel](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Group]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 8:33:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Group](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [EntityLevelID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Group] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Region]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 8:33:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Region](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CountryID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Region] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[School]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 8:33:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[School](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CenterID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_School] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[User]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 8:33:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserJobs]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 8:33:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserJobs](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EntityID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserJobs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [UserID] ASC,
    [GroupID] ASC,
    [EntityID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Assocation] ([ID], [Name], [CityID]) VALUES (1, N'KH', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Assocation] ([ID], [Name], [CityID]) VALUES (2, N'mkh_ass', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Center] ([ID], [Name], [AssociationID]) VALUES (1, N'NorthCenter', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Center] ([ID], [Name], [AssociationID]) VALUES (2, N'SouthCenter', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[City] ([ID], [Name], [RegionID]) VALUES (1, N'Jeddah', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[City] ([ID], [Name], [RegionID]) VALUES (2, N'MakkahCiry', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (1, N'Class1', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (2, N'Class2', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (3, N'class3', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (4, N'class4', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Country] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'KSA')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Country] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (2, N'UAE')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (1, N'Country', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (2, N'Region', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (3, N'City', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (4, N'Association', 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (5, N'Center', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (6, N'School', 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (7, N'Class', 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (1, N'Country Manager', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (2, N'Region Manager', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (3, N'City Manager', 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (4, N'Association Manager', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (5, N'Center Manager', 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (6, N'School Manager', 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (7, N'Teacher', 7)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Region] ([ID], [Name], [CountryID]) VALUES (1, N'Makkah', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Region] ([ID], [Name], [CountryID]) VALUES (2, N'Riyadh', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[School] ([ID], [Name], [CenterID]) VALUES (1, N'School1', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[School] ([ID], [Name], [CenterID]) VALUES (2, N'School2', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[School] ([ID], [Name], [CenterID]) VALUES (3, N'School3', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'UserA')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (2, N'UserB')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (3, N'UserC')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (4, N'UserD')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (5, N'UserE')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (6, N'UserF')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (7, N'UserG')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (8, N'UserH')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (9, N'UserI')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (10, N'UserJ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (2, 2, 2, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (3, 3, 3, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (4, 4, 4, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (5, 5, 5, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (6, 6, 6, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (7, 7, 7, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (8, 8, 2, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (9, 9, 3, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (10, 10, 4, 2)
GO
```

any solution for that ...

Comment: Your `PARENT_ID` values are incorrect. Specifically, how are UserJ and UserI linked in the data? What table and field says that UserJ is linked to and below UserI, or that UserI is linked to and above UserJ?

Comment: @LaughingVergil they are relating together through the UserJobs And Groups (and as you see in the Group there is entityLevel) and `UserJ` Comes in the `Association` which is under `UserI` in `City` Level

Answer (score 1):

I will repeat that your `PARENT_ID` values are incorrect. Let us look in detail on the UserI (ID = 9) query to see why.

```
  SELECT T1.ID, UserId,  NULL AS PARENT_ID, T1.GroupID, G.EntityLevelID
  FROM #UserJobs T1
  INNER JOIN #GROUP G ON T1.GROUPID = G.ID
  inner join #EntityLevel el on G.EntityLevelID = el.Id 
  WHERE T1.UserID = 9
```

This would be the base query when processing UserI, as defined in your data *(NOTE: I used temp tables instead of permanent tables to simplify cleanup after the tests)*  The output of this query fragment looks like this:

```
ID  UserId  PARENT_ID   GroupID EntityLevelID
9       9   NULL            3       3
```

No problem so far. So, the recursion portion of your CTE is:

```
  UNION ALL

  SELECT T2.ID, T2.UserId,  EL.ParentID, T2.GroupID, G.EntityLevelID
  FROM #UserJobs T2
  INNER JOIN #GROUP G ON T2.GROUPID = G.ID
  inner join #EntityLevel el on G.EntityLevelID = el.Id
  INNER JOIN MyCTE itms 
      ON EL.ParentID >= itms.ID -- <<<< PROBLEM!!
```

As we see above, the value in `itms.ID` for the first part of this query is [9]. This needs to join to a value in the `#EntityLevel.ParentID` field. But if you look in the values you are inserting into the #EntityLevel table, your highest `ParentID` value is a [6].  Since there is no record matching the `itms.ID` value, no additional records are linked.

A similar problem comes with the UserID = 3 record (Examine the output of the queries to figure out why).

To recap - If you want an item to be linked to another item in a tree, there must be a specific, unique link between the items. You need to ensure that the specific, unique link exists. Note that it does not need to be a single data value, but every time your tree forks, the elements on one branch must be identifiably distinct from the elements on the other branch based on their data values.

Comment: Thank you, but how you think I can solve this problem. as you know, I need to use this query in order to see every user under a specific user, and later on I need to use the same query to brings out a tree from a specific point from the tree.

Comment: do you think that i can achieve what i need in different table relations or with eliminating some Unused tables

Comment: There are several different ways to represent a tree in SQL Server. The simplest is to have your parent pointer actually point to the record that actually is its parent - that is, a parentID at the User level. Another is to express your tree as a number range per User - for example, with the tree shown above,.. well, it will be easier to explain with a link. See [Nested Set Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) at Wikipedia. This is fast and efficient, but not intuitive. Once you figure it out, it is very efficient.

Comment: but i cannot make the parent in the `User` Level because it's actually on the Entity Level, how about if we add an if statement in the ` ON EL.ParentID >= itms.ID` to make sure that we have another condition to check witch is the `Entity Level`, Actually the Nested set model will not work in my case

Comment: and back to your answer when you said `your PARENT_ID values are incorrect` how that will be i'm fully agreed that the parent can be considered from more than one relation. is that true for now, so do you see that Really `UserI` not related to `UserJ` they are relating through the groups `UserI` on `City` Level and `UserJ` is on `Association` Level